# Chartist.js Stacked Bar Graph with Round Corners / Edges

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart with round edges where the overlapping part of the bottom "series" is displayed on top of the top series.

[This is what I am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5V4s.png)

[And here is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G2yU.png)

I tried using stacking order with `position: absolute` on the parent element and `z-index` on the child bar elements but that didn't work.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
const chart = new this.Chartist.Bar(".barChart",
  {
    labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
    series: [[2, 8, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10], [13, 7, 13, 11, 10, 7, 5]]
  },
  {
    stackBars: true
  }
);
```

And my css:

```
  .ct-series-a {
    .ct-bar {
      stroke: url(#gradient);
      stroke-width: 1rem;
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }
  }
  .ct-series-b {
    .ct-bar {
      stroke: lightgray;
      stroke-width: 1rem;
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }
  }
```

Has anyone done anything similar? Thanks in advance!